# How to stop Google from translating a language for good

Tags: localization, translation, google-account

English isn't my mother tongue and not a main language where I live either. But I have a certificate for C1 level english. So I added English to my spoken languages in my google account and even switched some services like Youtube over to English, tried to disable translation for english etc... However, Google still realizes I am in a non-english speaking country and keeps bothering me with stuff like:

- Auto enabling english subs on mobile youtube
- Randomly and terribly auto translating titles in youtube on desktop and mobile
- on Chrome Mobile constantly asking me if I want to translate english texts

How can I tell google that I would like to read english texts in english for good and that it shan't ever bother me again about it in all of their services?

Answer (score 1):

You can use chrome extension I created to disable YouTube titles translations

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/yt-anti-translate/ndpmhjnlfkgfalaieeneneenijondgag

It's free and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the language setting of your browser and set it to English I think it will avoid this problem.

Comment: This won't fix it for stuff like the youtube app. Is there no google-account-wide way to disable translation for specified languages? This seems like something they'd have *somewhere*..

Answer (score -1):

Are you on chrome? if so then go here https://myaccount.google.com/language and change the language.

Comment: I did. English is my main language there.